# Enforcing single weekly entry in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

My application allows users to make one, and one only, weekly entry in another table. Enforcing this idea causes the usual problems, I might commit a record after checking `ifExists` on another connection and end up with two records. I cannot optimistically lock a record that doesn't exist and want to avoid pessimistic locking over the whole table.

So what is the best solution here? Create the records for all the users every week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second table which contains the Weeks (eg. WeekId, StartDate, EndDate).

Then in your first table create two foreign key relationships one to the User table and a second to the Week table.
Then add a unique constraint to ensure that you only get one record per user per week.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.UserWeeks
  ADD CONSTRAINT uq_UserWeeks UNIQUE(UserId, WeekId);
```

The second insert will fail due to the unique constraint.

Comment: What purpose does the foreign key have here?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a foreign key, but it must uniquely represent the week in question, could be a date for the start of the week. I would think this is a good candidate for normalizing the data